# Is this a valid Stack Overflow question, and if so how might I improve it so it can be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Yesterday I asked this question  [Is there an official or common knowledge standard minimal interface for a "list-like" object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28841735), which is now closed for not being about programming.

Is my question a valid question for Stack Overflow? And if not, how can I improve it so it can be reopened? I have been told that it is a "rant" and have tried to implement all feedback from people regarding question improvements, however it was still closed.

I am slightly frustrated not by the fact that it was closed, but by the complete lack of constructive criticism on the part of those who voted to close it. I attempted to ask [msw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282912/msw) who voted to close as a rant for some constructive feedback, however they did not seem interested in giving me any.

I have no desire to "arm-wrestle" over the subject, nor do I feel any emotional attachment to my question, I simply want to understand what is still wrong with my question, and whether there is anything I can do to fix it, so I can improve upon my question-asking in the future. At this juncture I cannot understand why my question is not suitable for Stack Overflow, and would love an explanation which details either why my question cannot be improved, or how I might improve it.

**UPDATE:**
The question has been reopened by community vote.

Comment: I could see why some people would flag it as opinion based. Even the first answer is "could be ..." "I would..." which is the opinion of the answerer, not a fact. Would that be enough to close it? I doubt that.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to use so much bold in your questions, if any at all. Your SO question only uses it in two places, so that's not too bad. But this one has a lot of extra bold in it that I don't think you really need. Also, you shouldn't add signatures to your posts, such as your "Many thanks in advance." sign-off here and on the SO post, as they are considered noise and unnecessary.

Comment: @Kendra Look better now? Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Elizion Considerably. Glad you took it to heart without getting upset about it. Kudos on that, and trying to understand how to improve your question. :)

Comment: I feel like there's some subtle word choice that nudges the question towards opinion-based. For example, "agreed" somewhat implies that you'd be willing to accept community consensus on what the interface could be. This encourages each user to submit their interpretation and establish consensus via upvotes. If you had said "official" instead, then it permits only replies that explicitly quote the documentation/source code/dev mailing list.

Comment: @Kevin That makes sense. I just put "agreed" in case it was something that, although not being documented, is common knowledge or assumed. Would it be appropriate for me to edit my question at this point?

Comment: I think that would be fine, although I don't know if it will actually have any impact on future close voters. It's only my opinion, after all ;-)

Comment: @Kevin LOL very true. I lean towards agreeing with you, "agreed" is probably an awfully subjective term. Thanks :)

Comment: [tag:status-mass-upvoted]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The question is rather broad and opinion-based, because the term used is not clearly defined.

Antti has you covered with a very good answer, but the question remains wide open for anyone else piping in an opinion as to what *they* think *list-like* can mean.

Comment: As I said, given the term does not have a standardized or agreed minimal interface requirement *which I now know* there's going to be many opinions. But is it not okay to ask if a standard/ agreed minimal interface exists? It's not like I asked "What do you think a list-like object means?"

Comment: Your title does ask that, or could be interpreted to.

Comment: @CodeCaster I suppose so, good point. Edited my title to match my interior question.

Comment: If you could look at my updated question and see if there's any insight you could provide, that would be incredibly appreciated :)

Comment: @Elizion: your question has already been reopened by community vote, I don't think anything further needs to be said, really.

Comment: That happened rather quickly. Many thanks.